# Different types of indentation

Tags: indentation

I was trying to make a longer indentation in a document. At the moment I have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 9in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tipa}\setlength{\parindent}{1em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}
\begin {center}
\Large \bfseries{Table of Contents}
\end{center} \\ 
\vspace{1cm}
\noindent
\textbf {1 Introduction} \dotfill 4 \\
\indent \emph {1.1 Text} \dotfill 3 \\
\indent \emph {1.1.1 more text}  \dotfill 3\\
\end{document}
```

What I would like to do it to move the "1.1.1 more text" further right from the previous "1.1 text". I have tried \hspace{1cm},\parident and other similar coding. My document is not reacting to any of these and just seems to stay the same. I was hoping to do it in a simple code without sections and subsections. Am I using the wrong packages?

Thank you in advance and Im sorry if its an obvious question.

Comment: You should remove all the `\\ ` and `\indent` neither have any place in a latex document as a rule (apart from the use of `\\ ` to end table rows) the  `\\ ` after `center` generates an error, and the last one generates an underful box badness 10000 warning (which is as bad as it can be)

Comment: as posted you get an error due to 2 `\docuemntclass` commands.

Comment: Welcome! In addition to what @DavidCarlisle said, `\bfseries` doesn't take an argument. `\bfseries{text}` is just like `\bfseries text`.

Comment: I think you might want to step back from this and rethink your strategy. You say, `I was hoping to do it in a simple code without sections and subsections` but you seem to be trying to do something far more complicated than using sections and subsections! Please do not be offended, but you are trying to use LaTeX as most people use a word processor i.e. specifying how things should *look* rather than what they *mean*. Not only does that undermine a great deal of the point of using LaTeX. It also makes life much more difficult, because LaTeX is designed *not* to be used that way.

Comment: You generate the table of contents with `\tableofcontents`. You start a section with `\section{<title of section>}`. That's all. (And loading `tocloft` won't do any good at all if you don't use semantic mark-up as you won't be able to use any of the features it provides.)

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned, your document should look more like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[total={6in, 9in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\renewcommand*\contentsname{Table of Contents}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecfont{\itshape}
\renewcommand\cftsubsubsecfont{\itshape}
\renewcommand\cftdotsep{2}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Introduction}
Some text here.
\newpage Some text here.
\newpage Some text here.
\subsection{Text}
Some text here.
\newpage
\subsubsection{More text}
\end{document}
```

[image: semantic markup results]

The result may not yet be what you want - it may require further adjustments, but the basic structure should look like this. (Although you will not need to artificially add `\newpage` just to get things on later pages for the example.)

That is, the main document body says what kind of thing each part of the document is: this is a section title, this is the table of contents, this is the bibliography.

If you want to change how the result *looks* you configure that using packages and so on in your preamble.

You let LaTeX figure out which page number subsubsection 9.8.5 starts on, so that if it changes, you don't have to think about it. And similarly for page styles, headers, footers and so on.

It is not like word processing and it can take getting used to because, if you've used a word processor for a long time, *of course* it seems simpler to do it the way you are used to. But, in the long run, it is much more complicated, creates inconsistent and inflexible results and forces you to think about all the things computers are great at and humans are hopeless at. Moreover, it is really not easy to use LaTeX that way. You can do it, but you will wish you had stayed using the word processor instead because you'll get all the disadvantages of LaTeX and none of the advantages.